# Scroll to bottom in overflowing React-Select Multi-select Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-select

I am using React-Select v2.4.4. I was trying various things for bringing scrollbar at bottom of multi-select input but none of them seems to work.

Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-89cry

In above link, when we select `Select All` option from drop down, scrollbar should automatically move to bottom and show below inputs:
[image]

I have tried 2 things but none of them is working.

1. I tried using `Ref` and below code:

   ```
   const scrollHeight = this.node.scrollHeight;
   const height = this.node.clientHeight;
   const maxScrollTop = scrollHeight - height;
   this.node.scrollTop = maxScrollTop > 0 ? maxScrollTop : 0;
   ```
2. Got element by using `document.getElementById()`, and then used `scrollIntoView`.

   ```
   const element = document.getElementById("select");
   element.scrollIntoView({
     behavior: "smooth",
     block: "end",
     inline: "nearest"
   });
   ```

Both of above methods are present in `scrollToBottom` function.

Is there something i am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: I've tried your sandbox on chrome and it's working fine (at least it's matching your screenshot in example). What are you seeing ?

Comment: @Laura I want scrollbar to automatically go to bottom when content overflows. So, now when i select `Select All`, scrollbar remains at top. I want it to go to bottom.

Comment: Well from your sandbox it does on Chrome. I can directly see `38`/`39` numbers

Comment: When clicked on `Select All`, only 1 to 19 are visible. I have to scroll to see remaining numbers.

Comment: What is your OS, browser and version ?

Comment: Mac, Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Laura I tried it on Windows chrome too. But there too scrollbar remains at top when `Select All` is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it without using any `scrollHeight` or `document.getElementById`.

I did passed a `ref` to `Select`.

```
ref={component => {
          this.node = component;
    }}
```

and then i used `this.node.blur()` to bring the focus out of `Input` and then `this.node.focus()` to again bring focus to it. This way, when `focus` is brought back to `Input`, scroll will automatically move to bottom.

Updated code is in same code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-89cry

You can try by giving following input:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
```

and then press `tab` or `enter`. You will notice that scrollbar is at bottom of `Input`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach can´t work because `ref` on the `Select` component is the component itself, not a DOM element.

The second approach can´t work either because the element with the id `select` (in your case) is not the element which has the overflow.

---

Thanks to the `classNamePrefix` prop you can easily access the DOM element of the `ValueContainer` component, which contains all the selected options and therefore has the overflow.

> **classNamePrefix**
>
> If provided, all inner components will be given a prefixed className attribute.
>
> This is useful when styling via CSS classes instead of the Styles API approach.
>
> --- [`react-select` documentation](https://react-select.com/props)

Just get the element with the `id == "select"` and find in it the element with the css-class `react-select__value-container`. You can then manipulate the scroll values on that element to scroll to the bottom.

```
scrollToBottom = () => {
    // element with `id` from `id` prop
    const container = document.getElementById('select');

    // `classNamePrefix` + component name
    const valueContainer = container.querySelector('.react-select__value-container');
    
    // Set scroll to maximum
    valueContainer.scrollTop = valueContainer.scrollHeight;
}
```